# Do irregular galaxies host a supermassive black hole?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, galaxies

Do irregular galaxies (eg the LMC) host a supermassive black hole?

Answer (score 2):

Some do, e.g. [NGC 6240](https://scitechdaily.com/three-supermassive-black-holes-discovered-at-the-core-of-one-galaxy/), but most don't. Rather they have "nuclear star clusters", which are dense knots of many thousands of stars, as explained [here](https://www.quora.com/Do-irregular-galaxies-have-supermassive-black-holes-at-the-center-If-yes-why-are-their-shapes-irregular-Are-they-irregular-because-they-are-in-the-process-of-two-galaxies-colliding-with-each-other) (by an  astrophysicist).

The LMC also doesn't:
https://astronomy.com/news/2018/08/teeny-tiny-galaxy-with-a-supermassive-black-hole

Comment: Note that NGC 6240 is a merger system, not a classical irregular galaxy like the LMC.